# couchbase index is not creating

Tags: couchbase, sql++

problem is occurred new index are not created show the error message [ { "code": 5000, "msg": "GSI CreatePrimaryIndex() - cause: Create index or Alter replica cannot proceed due to rebalance in progress, another concurrent create index request, network partition, node failover, indexer failure, or presence of duplicate index name.", "query": "CREATE PRIMARY INDEX customer_requests_indx ON customer_requests\n" } ]

Comment: Have you checked all of the possible causes listed in the error message?

Comment: yes checked only, presence of duplicate index. rest of them i don,t know how to check and solve the problem.

Comment: You can check indexer.log under /opt/couchbase/var/lib/couchbase/logs to look for errors and see if the indexer process is running fine. Have you been able to create any index before on this setup or is this the first one?

Comment: yes, lot of index create after couch base set but now problem is occurs index can not create right now. some times index build 100% but showing index not ready. and one more problem showing some previous few  index showing remaining mutations when add new data. please help me i am really thank full to you. Thank you for support

Comment: You can try to restart the indexer process and see if that helps(kill indexer process, it will restart automatically). Otherwise, need to look into the logs to see what the problem is. Which version are you using, CE/EE?

Comment: thanks for reply , community edition (CE) couchbase 6.5.0, can you
told me how to kill index processes) by any command .

Comment: http://34.196.238.149/lims/indexer.log this my indexer.log url

i can not understand what problem . please help me if possible to understand what problem in our couchbase end

Comment: To restart, you can look for "indexer" process in the "ps" output and "kill" the process.